# Can I define a variable globally then assign it locally and again use it another local method?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Can I define a variable globally then assign it locally and again use it as another local method in Java? I tried to fetch data from FireBase database locally. Using it I want to perform some task in another local method but the problem is I could not manage to get the data to another method. Is there any way to do it?

```
double slatitude,slongitude,currbal;
        DatabaseReference mDatabase= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        DatabaseReference mref,mlat,mlong,mstatus;
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.travel);
            // Get the Intent that started this activity and extract the string
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            String id = intent.getStringExtra(rfidreader.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
            // Capture the layout's TextView and set the string as its text
            textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message);
            //textView.setText(id+" "+"signed in successfully");
            mref=mDatabase.child(id).child("Balance");
            mlat=mDatabase.child(id).child("Start").child("Lat");
            mlong=mDatabase.child(id).child("Start").child("Long");
            mstatus=mDatabase.child(id).child("Status");
            getData(id);

        }
     public void getData(String input)
        {
            pssngrid = input;
            mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
                {
                    currbal = dataSnapshot.child(pssngrid).child("Balance").getValue(Double.class);
                    status = dataSnapshot.child(pssngrid).child("Status").getValue(Integer.class);
                    mlatiude = dataSnapshot.child(pssngrid).child("Start").child("Lat").getValue(Double.class);
                    mlongittude = dataSnapshot.child(pssngrid).child("Start").child("Long").getValue(Double.class);
                }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }
@Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if(currbal>=10)
        {
            gps = new GPSTracker(onTravel.this);
            double slatitude = gps.getLatitude();
            double slongitude = gps.getLongitude();
            if(status==0)
            {
                mlat.setValue(slatitude);
                mlong.setValue(slongitude);
                mstatus.setValue(1);
                textView.setText("Thank you,you are eligible for travelling....");


            }
            else if(status==1)
            {
                dis=HaverSineDistance(mlatitude,mlongitude,slatitude,slongitude);
                fare=dis*5;
                newbal=currbal-fare;
                mref.setValue(newbal);
                mstatus.setValue(0);
                textView.setText("Distance Traveled:"+dis+"\n"+"Current Balance:"+currbal+"\n"+"Fare:"+fare+"\n"+"Net Balance:"+newbal);

            }
        }
        else
        {
            textView.setText("Sorry,you are not eligible for travelling this time.Please recharge your card..");

        }
```

Comment: yes you can do this

Comment: Yes you can use it [here is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7591227/how-to-make-scope-of-variable-globalwithout-making-it-actually-global) detail use of global variable.

Comment: Which variable do you want to use in another method? Please responde with @

Comment: Yes, but you probably shouldn't.  I don't understand the problem that you're trying to solve, but I'm sure you can do it without resorting to globals.

Comment: here i want to use the values of variables -currbal ,status ,mlatiude,mlongittude  in onStart() method...but when i try to do this,i find that there isn't any values assigned to these variables...i have updated the code given above.please have a look

Comment: OnStart runs once for the Activity, and very early compared to the other code

Answer (score 0):

There's a difference between what you're doing, and actually making things truly "global" variables.

Private instance variables are how you share variables across methods, however you might be misunderstanding the Activity lifecycle and that Firebase does not  present data to your app in any guaranteed way according to it.

In other words, `onStart` will likely run first. Then `onCreate` and `getData`, and only after that, does the `onDataChange` event occur

Now you see the issue that `currbal` and `status` are  never assigned until much later that you've given.

---

The correct way to get data to update like this is to make the UI updates from the Firebase callback. And you don't need the fields if you pass through your needed values as parameters

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
} 

// separate this
private updateUI(String  pssngrid, DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) 
    double currbal = dataSnapshot.child(pssngrid).child("Balance").getValue(Double.class);
    int status = dataSnapshot.child(pssngrid).child("Status").getValue(Integer.class);
    double mlatiude = dataSnapshot.child(pssngrid).child("Start").child("Lat").getValue(Double.class);
     double mlongittude = dataSnapshot.child(pssngrid).child("Start").child("Long").getValue(Double.class);

    if(currbal>=10) {
      ...
```

And

```
public void getData(final String input) {
        mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
            {
                updateUI(input, dataSnapshot);
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

---

Also, remove all unnecessary DatabaseReference variables. You only need the one you're querying

You may want to additionally retrieve your Firebase data as a single Java object, rather than individually extracting the fields

Comment: but here, a problem occurs.whenever i update my data in database through onDataChange method it fires again automatically creating a loop of infinite times...mainly that's why i wanted to seperately retrieve data and update in database in another local method @cricket_007

Comment: That's how Firebase works. It's a realtime database. You get new data. It sends you updates, forcing it into another model says to me that you shouldn't use it... Have you tried Cloud Firestore instead?

Comment: i found the solution..Using addListenerForSingleValueEvent  i can fetch and update data only once.Thank you all :)

Comment: Well, sure. Though, you still should follow the flow of data I described